# TeamCity - Change branch name

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have a build configuration that builds following tags "develop", "master" and "hotfix" from my branches.

The problem is my branches are not called hotfix in git. They are called for example "hotfix/v1.1.5".

To change that I use the "Shorten Branch Name" feature from TeamCity. I have to do following in the VCS Root to get what I need:

```
+:refs/heads/(hotfix)/v1.1.5
```

You maybe can already see the problem. I have to do this for every new hotfix. Is there a way to get TeamCity to build all hotfix branches under the tag "hotfix"?

I tried this but it is not working.

```
+:refs/heads/(hotfix)/*
```

Comment: I wonder why do you want to label them all as hotfix, while they have different names in git?

Comment: It is a little bit difficult to explain but it has something to do with how they will get deployed. I deploy them to a test server using the branch names. I want all hotfixes to be deployed to the same place.

Comment: Maybe you can add a check to a build script: if the branch starts with hotfix/, use 'hotfix' for deployment.